# What modern 20 amp breaker is compatible with my Challenger panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I have a bad 20 amp challenger breaker that I need to replace. Can anyone tell me which replacement to buy. Here’s the info from the breaker:

- 20 Amp
- Challenger
- Und.Lab.Inc.Listed
- Circuit Breaker
- 1 pole unit.  E16248
- Issue No. MC-1253
- Type C 120/240 VAC
- 36 LB IN. LUG Torque
- HACR TYPE SWD
- LR 17630   13278-1 K

  [image]

Comment: Please post a photo of your panel. JACK would like to see it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing a Challenger breaker with an after-market breaker](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/91429/replacing-a-challenger-breaker-with-an-after-market-breaker)

Answer (score 18):

TLDR: Replace **every** breaker in your panel with a BR type from Bryant, Cutler Hammer or Eaton, readily available most places that sell breakers.  Nothing else should be in your panel - *especially not a Challenger (unless you like fires)!*

For the best answer ever on this subject, [see here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/141440/47125).

[image]

*Green highlighting added. The breakers don't actually have that.*

### You must use UL-listed or UL-classified breakers

**UL-listed** means the manufacturer of the panel makes the breakers using their internal knowledge, and UL certified it as safe.

**UL-Classified** means *a competitor* reverse-engineered it.  *UL has torture-tested it and confirmed it safe*.

**Never stick random Brand X breakers in your panel**. The bus stabs are different for patent reasons, and will arc and burn when heavily loaded.  We call these "alien breakers".

### Challenger is cursed...

Because of the need for backwards compatibility, one cannot change a bus design. But it's a good bus design. Unfortunately Challenger hopped on the FPE/Zinsco crazytrain and made some **very bad breakers** for that good bus.  That is why Challenger is on the same "remove it" list as FPE/Zinsco, but only insofar as the breakers, not the panel.

### ... but Challenger is blessed.

This industry runs on mergers and acquisitions.  Challenger/Westinghouse wound up in the hands of **Bryant** who promptly fixed the breaker problem. They changed its name to BR, so they could outlaw use of the defective Challenger Type C breakers. (The buses remain the same).  As for BR breakers, they cross-listed those Type C, since of course they fit Challenger.  **This gives Challenger panel owners a super easy upgrade path; simply swap out the vile Type C for Type BR/C for about $5/circuit**.

To be clear: BR/C isn't "UL-classified" for your panel.  It is "UL Listed" for your panel.  And your only legal choice.

BRyant got folded into **Cutler Hammer** who got folded into **Eaton**.  The buses are *still the same* to maintain backwards compatibility and because the original bus is perfectly fine.

### You must change every breaker in the panel to BR type

Since the Challenger breakers are dangerous, every breaker in your panel needs to be a Type BR/Type C from Bryant, Cutler Hammer or Eaton.  If it's not, change it now.

Also, where your breaker has failed, look closely at the bus stabs under the breaker.  Challenger never had a bus-stab problem, but lots of people don't know about the BR/C thing, so they run out and grab any "alien breaker" like a Square D HOMeline or GE or Murray.  Those could have burned up the bus.  A burned bus is unusable; that space is permanently dead. Search the panel for any other alien breakers and get rid of em.

An alien breaker can be a sleeping monster; most circuits aren't loaded very hard (until they are, and that's when it fries).

Comment: BTW: I'm not sure if your history of the origins of how Challenger used the BR bus stabs is quite correct -- C-H bought Bryant/Westinghouse out directly, to the best of my understanding

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yeah I thought I understood that lineage, but maybe not.

Comment: Yeah, furthermore, I'm pretty sure C-H bought Challenger directly after acquiring the Westinghouse distribution products

Answer (score 9):

Your "C" breaker can be replaced with an Eaton "BR" breaker. There are other breakers that will work but Eaton are probably more available... many home stores carry them.

Comment: As specified in this document https://eaton.nanorep.co/storage/nr1/kb/2AD62C9/45CAE24/33290C4D/1/EatonBreakers012412.pdf . Eaton is the current owner of the Westinghouse/Challenger brand.

Comment: I'm unaware of any other breakers that will work in a Challenger.  Nobody else makes Classified breakers for Eaton BR (and probably won't because Eaton keeps prices down so there's no margin in it).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- I think Jack is referring to the UBI/Conn. Electric Challenger breakers, which are rubbish (UBI has NFI how to do proper breaker QC)