# Should Challenger “Type A” breakers be replaced?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I have a Challenger branded Eaton sub-panel that contains 8 Challenger breakers. Most of them are “Type A” tandem (duplex) breakers, while the larger circuits are “Type C”.

In the answer to this question it was stated that all Challenger “Type C” breakers should be replaced with Eaton “Type BR” breakers:

[What modern 20 amp breaker is compatible with my Challenger panel?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/188609/what-modern-20-amp-breaker-is-compatible-with-my-challenger-panel)

My question is if the Challenger “Type A” breakers are safe to continue using or should I also replace all of them with equivalent Eaton “Type BRD” breakers?

Comment: Well, the criticisms of Challenger fall more on the company than on the breaker type, so I assume the taint applies to their tandems as well. Breakers are cheap, why fuss?

Answer (score 1):

### As long as the new breaker has the Type A marking on it, you're good

Current production BR tandem breakers, both CTL (type BD, with a BDxxxx part number) and non-CTL (type BRD, with a BRxxxx part number), are cross-labeled as Type A, so either will do as a replacement; it would be wise to replace them, though, just like you did with the Type C breakers.