# Breaker Switch only Working with Certain Lights

Tags: switch, circuit-breaker

Having some trouble with a breaker switch and everything thats part of that circuit. Out of the blue, some lights stopped working along with everything else that is hooked to that specific breaker.

I flipped the switch, tightened the screw a bit and then some of the lights started working again (garage, dining room).  Then when I went to turn on the front door light, the garage/dining room lights went off and everything on that circuit wouldn't come on.  I tried this a couple more times, removing the switch, making sure it was secure on the main panel but same issue.

Could this be linked to a bad switch and could simply replacing the switch be an easy fix?  I'm guessing not since some of the lights do power on.   Other possibilities?

Dont believe there is a GFCI on this circuit.

Attached a couple pics of the breaker on the main panel and after I've pulled it off.

Thank you

[image: Switch in panel]

[image: Switch off panel]

[image: Switch off panel2]

Comment: Can you post photos of the label on the inside of your breaker panel's door please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Didnt see any label on the door, heres a pic of the whole panel if it helps at all:
https://i.ibb.co/Vm6pX9w/PXL-20220829-031124019.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

What does the bus stab where the breaker came from look like? And what do the stab jaws on the breaker look like? Challenger breakers are **defective** even if used in Challenger panels, but they are completely inappropriate in a Murray panel (judging by the rest of your breakers).

The incorrect breaker may have damaged your breaker bus, leading to a bad connection. You may have to move the circuit to a fresh space (in addition to a fresh, correct breaker).

See [What modern 20 amp breaker is compatible with my Challenger panel?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/188609/what-modern-20-amp-breaker-is-compatible-with-my-challenger-panel) and other questions on this site.