Why do I measure 120 Volts at the breaker when it’s turned off?
A friend's house had outlets go out in the garage and in one of the bathrooms and rooms. I went into the attic and checked for junction boxes. All the cables are direct to the circuit panel with no junctions.
I opened up all of the outlets that had no power to check the wiring and found one that was burnt in the bathroom. It had no GFCI, so I replaced it with a GFCI. I also replaced the circuit breaker, because it had a delay-on reaction.
I also checked all of the outlets in the house to see if I had a hot neutral. All checked out good. I still have 120 at the circuit breaker when turned on and none of the outlets work still.


Picture of the panel? How are you measuring to get "120 at the circuit breaker"?

What is a "delay on reaction"?

Possible you have a typo of "off" instead of "on".  This would make sense of having 120v at the breaker.  Power at the breaker and no power in the circuit means a bad connection or a broken wire, either hot or neutral or both somewhere in the circuit.

I am quite sure I had it turned off and the delayed reaction on the breaker when I took it off and cycled off and on the off clicked and the on made a thud sound a nanosecond later

Re "delayed reaction": Challenger breakers (as indicated in your follow-up post) are all known-defective, so that's not shocking. They all need to be replaced promptly, with known-good compatible breakers such as Bryant/Eaton BR: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/188609/what-modern-20-amp-breaker-is-compatible-with-my-challenger-panel https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/141440

I've voted to reopen. The photo goes a long way to clearing some things up.

@nobody,  the other question has no context. It's just a photo, apparently intended as an update to this question. It should've been closed for lack of details by the experienced users who posted answers.

That panel is a hot mess.  Those old Crouse Hinds style "thin" breakers are dangerous, and should be replaced with Eaton Type A (marketed as BR) tandems and quadplex as needed.   That 50A breaker is popped mostly out, possibly because of damage to the very fragile bus clip.  This is a Federal Pacific tier "FixRightNow".  Separate from that, Challenger breakers have a refusal-to-trip problem and should be replaced with Eaton Type A or C (marketed as BR).  Type A and C are for Challenger panels.
